# document.removeEventListener not fire in useEffect return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I use  React  transitions group with Router
When moving to another page it does not remove the listener
It only removes the listener when moving and reloading

```
function IntroPage() {

 function Herotilt(event) {
     var Tilt = document.getElementById("showcase-tilt");
     var maxTilt = 1.5;

     var xPos = (event.pageX / window.screen.width) * (maxTilt * 2) - maxTilt;
     var yPos = (event.pageY / window.screen.height) * (maxTilt * 2) - maxTilt;
     gsap.set(Tilt, { transformPerspective: 2000, transformOrigin: "center" });
     gsap.to(Tilt, 0.2, {
      rotationY: xPos,
      rotationX: yPos,
      ease: Power1.easeOut,
      overwrite: true,
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => { // start useEffect Hook

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => { //Start EventListener
    Herotilt(event);
    console.log("from Intro");
   }); // end EventListener

    return function cleanUp() { //start Clean Function
     console.log("Clean UP");
     document.removeEventListener("mousemove", Herotilt);
      }; // end Clean Function 

   }, []); // end useEffect Hook

} // end Function Component
```

Comment: Why are you not doing just `document.addEventListener("mousemove", Herotilt)`? Can you try that instead see if it helps?

Comment: This leaves some time after loading the other page as removing the listener
Is this possible because of React transitions group

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thx Alex it's work probably now

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here:

1. The cleanup function needs to be returned *within* the useEffect block ([take a look at the docs here for an example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)).
2. You can't remove event listeners that use anonymous functions, so you'll need to add Herotilt as directly to the addEventListener call. JavaScript will automatically pass the event into event listener callbacks.

Take a look at the code below. I've removed the Herotilt function body just to draw more attention to the actual fixes.

Hope this helps!

```js
function IntroPage() {

 function Herotilt(event) {
     // Do stuff here...
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Pass in the function by name.
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", Herotilt);

    // The return block goes within useEffect().
    return function cleanUp() {
        console.log("Clean UP");
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", Herotilt)
    };

 }, []);
```

Comment: cleanUp function is already within the useEffect This leaves some time after loading the other page as removing the listener Is this possible because of React transitions group

Comment: In the code you posted in your question, the `cleanUp()` function is outside of `useEffect().` Note that `});` closes the useEffect function on the line before `return cleanUp()`. It must be inside of useEffect.

Comment: no this brackets for addEventListener not for useEffect , useeffect take a array of dep at the second argument

Comment: Correct: useEffect takes an array of dependencies as the second argument. The cleanUp function is supposed to be the return value from the *first* argument. Look at the example in the docs: the `cleanUp()` function is returned from *inside* the useEffect function. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Comment: The code  above is correct in order of order. I will put some comments so that you can see it better

Comment: You're right it is. The indentation was throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save the lambda which you are creating in `addEventListener` to variable and pass it to `removeEventListener` instead

```js
useEffect(() => {

  const callback = (event) => {
    Herotilt(event);
    console.log("from Intro");
  }

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", callback);
  return function cleanUp() {
    console.log("Clean UP");
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", callback);
  };

}, []);
```

...or just pass `Herotilt` function without wrapping them in another function